# How to have a parameter in a closure when using @ViewBuilder

Tags: swiftui

I am passing a view to another view, like this:

```
struct MyView<Content:View>: View {

  private var content: Content

  init(@ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.content = content()
  }
```

To use that I will do

```
MyView {
  MyContent()
}
```

but what I want is to pass a parameter in the closure, like

```
MyView {value in
 MyContent()
}
```

How do I declare the view to have that?

Comment: Don't pass views, pass data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```swift
struct MyView<Content:View, T>: View {

    private let data: T
    private let content: (T) -> Content

    init(_ data: T, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (T) -> Content) {
        self.data = data
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        content(data)
    }
}

struct String2Text: View {
    let string: String

    init(_ string: String) {
        self.string = string
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(string)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyView("hello") { value in
            String2Text(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fantastic. THANKS!